# can a number of the form $x^2 + 1 $ be a square number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have been trying to prove that $x^2 + 1 $ is not a perfect square (other than $0^2 +1^2=1^2$). I'm stuck and can't move forward.

The thing I have tried so is to relate the problem to a hyperbola and find an integer solution for both $x$ and $y$ when $a=b=1$. The pell's equation came up in my search, but I don't understand it fully.

---

<sup>Note: I was in a confused state and @CoolHandLouis' visual answer cleared my muddled mind, so I selected that answer. In that way, his answer was very helpful to me.  @Alessandro's proof is clear to me now and if I could accept two answers, I would accepted that one too.  Thanks to everyone for helping!</sup>

Comment: What is the largest perfect square less than $x^2 + 1$?

Comment: If $x^2 + 1 = y^2$ then $1 = (y-x)(y+x)$ and both factors are integers...

Comment: $0^2 + 1 = 1$ is a perfect square

Comment: As @Arthur points out, what is $x$?  Can $x$ be zero?  Is $x$ a positive integer?

Comment: @Winther I was trying that but couldn't follow through ..I know there is some obvious thing I'm missing .can you please elaborate

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche sorry for not mentioning . I'm not looking for the trivial solution

Comment: Square number + 1 = square number  ?   what an amazing number.

Comment: @GaryB I know I sound stupid but proving it has been difficult for me.

Comment: @GaryB - It's not supposed to be $x^2+ 1 = x^2$. It's supposed to be $x^2 + 1 = y^2$, which isn't too farfetched. Although it is provably impossible.

Comment: $\forall{x>1}:x^2<x^2+1<(x+1)^2$

Comment: @Ramkumar If $ab =1$ and $a,b$ are integers then we must have $a=1$ and $b=1$. This gives $y-x=1$ and $y+x=1$ with solution $x=0$ and $y=1$.

Comment: @Aleksander,who said x^2+1=x^2   ??

Comment: Ramkumar - I edited your post to present your reason for selecting my answer in a neutral tone since this will be viewed in the future by people who have no understanding of the dynamic issue. There is never a need to feel sorry about selecting an answer that you feel helped you. The overall general value of Allesandro's answer is evident in the points it received. Another option for you is to remove the commentary from the question, and post it as a comment under my question with an FYI to @Allesandro. Then questions and answers stand on their own and commentary is in comments.

Comment: @Ramkumar - Since I did take the liberty to edit your post, please do indicate if that represents what you want to say.  I'm just glad that *all of us* could help you! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We want to prove $x^2 + 1$ can never be a perfect square.

Let

- $f(x) = x^2$

  Then,

  $f(x)$     $<$       $f(x) + 1$      $<$      $f(x+1)$

  $x^2$           $<$        $x^2 + 1$     $<$      $x^2 + 2x + 1$        (for all $x > 0$).

Therefore, $x^2 + 1$ cannot be a perfect square (except $x = 0$) because it will always be greater than the prior perfect square and less than the next perfect square.

The following table illustrates this.  Note that $f(x)$ is the set of ***all perfect squares:***

```
x    f(x)=x^2       x^2+1       f(x+1)    
0        0            1            1     
1        1            2            4        
2        4            5            9        
3        9           10           16        
4       16           17           25
```

Comment: Thanks @CoolHandLouis but I wanted to know why ? why can't we have a perfect square for g(x).I was looking for a way to either prove or disprove it.

Comment: I just added a clarification:  because f(x) < g(x) < f(x+1).  The series of f(x) is the series of all perfect squares, and other than f(0), f(x) < g(x) < f(x+1).

Comment: yeah you are right .please edit you answer to include the $f(x) < g(x) < f(x+1)$ equates to $x^2< x^2 +1 <X^2+2X+2 $ in you answer and i'll select yours

Comment: I thought it made sense to me but when I was trying your proof .you assumption that $g(x) < f(x+1)$ came up and I was quickly doing the expansion of the $g(x) ,f(x+1)$ terms and thought that the underlying proof is still the same as Alessandro's

Comment: +1 for so much effort and a pretty good explanation. (And of course your postscript.)

Comment: I don't know, if I were you, I'd strip it down to "the answer proper" (I was tempted to during my edit). I may be old and ignorant about the latest social media trends, but I do know one thing: some people on the Internet are going to be petty and downvote your answer for reasons that have nothing to do with your answer's intrinsic merits.

Comment: The OP was looking for a proof and this answer could be misconstrued as being a proof, but it does not have the complete rigor required to be an acceptable proof. If there were a disclaimer to the effect of "this is not a proof, merely a way to look at it that might help you find your own proof", then I would consider it a decent answer. I feel like the table of examples distracts from the actual algebra being done, and the section that doesn't use LaTeX for the math is very hard to read.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Rigorous enough to be acceptable by whom? Note that someone even suggested that Alessandro's answer could have been more formal (rigorous)! My proof had just the right amount of rigor (not too much, not too little) to be helpful and selected as the accepted answer by the OP.  The table of examples did not distract but enhanced the understanding for the OP. I think I framed this answer--including a note on levels of rigor--fairly and clearly in the Preface and Postscript.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Thanks for LaTeX suggestion! I don't know LaTeX, but will clean this up later when I get a chance, and will be sure to use LaTeX in future answers.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks Point well taken, and thank you so much for the edits. It was a dynamic situation, the preface/postscript made the point needed at the time, but they are no longer relevant, so I removed them.  Thanks.

Comment: @ToddWilcox to your point about tables, I moved them to the end for a better overall presentation.  Thanks.

Comment: For posterity, note that this answer evolved to be more rigorous and proof-like, which may make some "not rigorous" comments dated.  The OP found the table helpful in comprehending the concept, which is why this answer was selected.

Answer (score 25):

$(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$, that is, the difference of consecutive squares is the $n$-th odd number.

Since 1 is the first odd number it is the difference of the second and the first square: $0^2+1=1^2$

Comment: sorry I was not looking for the first trivial solution.

Comment: My argument shows that it's the only one, subtracting bigger consecutive squares you obtain bigger odd numbers

Comment: For a formal proof, you would have to consider the possibility of two squares of numbers more than $1$ apart.

Comment: If $x^2$ and $x^2+1$ are both squares they must be consecutive squares, since they are consecutive numbers and for nonnegative distinct integers $a^2<b^2<c^2$ iff $a<b<c$

Comment: I understand all the other answers, but not this one. Since it has gotten 22 upvotes, I am sure I am missing something. Can someone elaborate how this argument shows $x^2+1$ is not a perfect square for $x>0$?

Comment: @Prism: If $x^2$ and $x^2+1$ are both squares than they must be consecutive squares, so we only need to show that they can't be consecutive squares and not that they can't both be squares. The difference between $(x+1)^2$ and $x^2$ is $2x+1$. In our case we want this difference to be $1$, solving $2x+1=1$ we find that $x=0$ is the only solution, so the only 2 consecutive squares with difference $1$ are $0^2$ and $(0+1)^2$.

Comment: Yes, now your comment has made it much more clear. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 17):

If $x>1$, then $x^2+1$ cannot be a perfect square because $x^2<x^2+1<(x+1)^2$.

In other words, $x^2+1$ lies between the two consecutive perfect squares $x^2$ and $(x+1)^2$.

Answer (score 9):

If $x,y$ are integers with $x^2+1=y^2$, then $1=y^2-x^2=(y+x)(y-x)$. The only integer factorizations of $1$ are $1=1\cdot 1=(-1)\cdot (-1)$, hence $x=0$ and $y=\pm1$.

Answer (score 2):

There's a more general result called [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (now proved).

$$x^y+1$$ is never a [perfect power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_power) for any natural $x,y>1$ (except for $(x,y)=(2,3)$).

Answer (score 1):

Given an integer $n$, $n^2 = n \times n$. That's obvious enough.

But what's $n^2 - (n - 1)^2$? As it turns out, it's $2n - 1$ (let me know if you want me to elaborate on that).

Then we're looking for solutions to $n^2 = x^2 + 1$ where $x$ is also an integer. Since both $n$ and $x$ are integers, $n^2$ and $x^2$ must be consecutive perfect squares. This leads to $$n^2 - x^2 = 2n - 1 = 1.$$ The only possible solution with $n$ positive is $n = 1$, so that $2n = 2$ and $2 - 1 = 1$.

What if we allow negative integers? There is one other solution: $n = 0$, $x = -1$.

There is also something called imaginary numbers. There might be a solution among them, but I only barely understand that concept, so I wouldn't even be able to begin looking for a solution among those.