# Multiplying two expressions containing perfect squares to get another perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Is it possible to multiply a perfect square by the previous square plus one and get another perfect square?

An example that doesn't work:
$$6^2 (5^2 + 1) = 936 \ne n^2$$

Comment: But $26$ is not a perfect square, neither is $6^2\cdot 26$.

Comment: "1 more then the perfect square 1 below the other one"??? What is that supposed to mean? Please rephrase your question using proper mathematical notation.

Comment: I assume you mean the following: Let $x$ be some number, then is it possible to find a perfect square $y^2$ that satisfies:$$y^2=x^2((x-1)^2+1)$$

Comment: @Mufasa No, if $x$ is some fixed number, then $y^2$ is fixed. The problem is finding $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $y^2=x^2((x-1)^2+1)$.

Comment: @user31415 - yes sorry - I worded it badly but meant it in the manner you described. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: The only such perfect square is $1^2$. We have $1^2((1-1)^2+1)=1^2$. Proofs of this are below.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking for integer solutions to $y^2=x^2((x-1)^2+1)$.
$n^2$ and $n^2+1$ are both perfect squares [iff $n=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105044/can-a-number-of-the-form-x2-1-be-a-square-number/1105051#1105051), so we can assume that $(x-1)^2+1$ isn't a perfect square (you can quickly check the case $x=1$ by hand, it is the only solution).

When you factorize $(x-1)^2+1$ it must be divisible by a prime with an odd exponent since it isn't a square, while the factorization of $x^2$ contains only primes with an even exponent so their product $x^2(x-1)^2+1$ must contain a prime with an odd exponent and hence can't be a square

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of two perfect squares is a perfect square, so we have to find a perfect square in the form $(x-1)^2+1$.

Comment: the only perfect square in such a form is $1$ and so $x=1$, which means $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is the only solution of $y^2=x^2((x-1)^2+1)$ (for compleness).

Comment: If we are considering the Gaußian integers $((i+1)-1)^2+1=0^2$.