# Prove that $x^2+1$ cannot be a perfect square for any positive integer x?

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, square-numbers

I started this problem by trying proof by contradiction.

I first noted that the problem stated that $x$ had to be a positive integer, and thus $x=0$ could not be a solution. I then assumed that $x^2+1=n^2$ for some integer $n$ other than $1$. From here I have tried various methods, to no avail:

- **Factoring:**

$n^2-x^2=1\implies(n+x)(n-x)=1$. It would be nice if I could say $(n+x)=(n-x)=1$ and $(n+x)=(n-x)=-1$. However, the issue here is that $(n+x)$ and $(n-x)$ could take on any value. For example, $(n+x)=2$ and $(n-x)=\frac{1}{2}$, or $(n+x)=3$ and $(n-x)=\frac{1}{3}$. Thus, I ruled out factoring.

- **For any number $n$, $n\equiv 0 \pmod4$ or $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.**

The trouble with this is that I would have to prove the above statement, so I ruled this out.

Does anyone have any tips on how to continue? I feel like this should be an easy proof, but no solutions are coming to me, without having to prove something else.

Comment: Your factoring is correct. Since $x,n$ are integers, $x-n$ is a natural number.

Comment: (x-n) cannot equal 1/2 because you have already said that x and n are integers.

Comment: But continuing down the factoring method, I would have $x+n=x-n\implies$$n=0$ and $x$ is all real numbers.

Comment: @JunlinYi What's wrong with that?  Once you have $n=0$ you get $x^2+1 = 0$.  There are so many paths that lead to a contradiction.  You seem to be losing sight of the fact that you can use all the information you have deduced so far, and unnecessarily restricted yourself to just the previous line.  E.g. in your comment you started with $x+n = x-n$ and then you forgot that you also had $(n+x)(n-x) = 1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can a number of the form $x^2 + 1 $ be a square number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105044/can-a-number-of-the-form-x2-1-be-a-square-number)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your factoring is abosolutely correct. However, since $x,n$ are integers, this gives us  $x-n$ is a natural number. Thus $x-n = \pm 1$.

An alternate proof would use that a square can not exist between two consecutive squres and $$x^2 < n^2 < x^2+2x+1$$

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate on how to continue down the factoring method? I cannot get it to work.

Comment: @JunlinYi $(x-n)(x+n)=1$, as you said yourself. But since $x,n$ are integers, $x-n$, $x+n$ are also integers. This implies that $x-n$ divides $1$, and thus that $x-n=1, x+n=1$ or $x-n=-1, x+n=-1$.

Comment: Oh, sorry I made a mistake in my algebra. So, continuing, I would have $x=0$ and $n=1$ or $-1$ as the only solutions, which does not follow the problem's specification that $x$ had to be positive. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

For any $n$, the square is $n^2$.

The following integer is $n+1$, and its square is $n^2 + 2n + 1$.

Since (assuming $x>0$) $$x^2 < x^2+1 < x^2 + 2x + 1$$

it also true that  $$x = \sqrt{x^2}  < \sqrt{x^2+1} < \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 1} = x+1$$ but there are no integers between $x$ and $x+1$.

Comment: Oh, that's a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun (and also because this approach could apply to other similar problems), I propose a solution using Gaussian integers. So consider the extension **Q**(i)/**Q** and its norm map N. The diophantine equation $x^2$ +1 = $n^2$ can also be written N(*x* + i) = N(*n*), or equivalently *x* + i = n*z*, where  *z*  is an element of **Q**(i) with norm 1. According to Hilbert's thm. 90, such a  *z*  is a quotient (*a* + i*b*)/(*a* - i*b*), where a priori *a* and *b* belong to **Q**. But the form of the fraction obviously allows us to take for *a* and *b* two coprime integers. Solving the real and imaginary parts, we get the two equations:    *x* = *n* ($a^2$ - $b^2$)/($a^2$ + $b^2$) and 1 = 2 *n* *ab*/($a^2$ + $b^2$), which give in turn 2 *x* = ($a^2$ - $b^2$)/*ab*. But the RHS fraction is irreducible: if a prime *p* divides the denominator, *p* will for instance divide *a* but not *b*, hence *p* will not divide the numerator. This contradicts the integrality of the LHS. Note that we did not need to suppose *x* positive.

Comment: can you provide such proof with only the basic properties of gaussian integers?

Comment: What do you mean by "basic properties of gaussian integers"? As I can see, outside the definitions, I only used Hilbert's 90, which is a classical result of Galois theory (and can be proved directly in the case of quadratic fields).

Comment: can you prove it for gaussian integer?

Comment: can you prove it without the Galois theory, and only with basic number theory?

Comment: Well, if we visualize $\mathbf Q (i) $ as the (u,v)-plane $\mathbf Q^2$, the problem is equivalent to the rational parametrisation of the unit circle: take $a>b$ in $\mathbf N$ and draw the line with slope $b/a$ through the point (-1,0); it is immediately seen that the second intersection point has coordinates $u=a^2 - b^2/a^2 + b^2 , v=2ab/a^2 + b^2$, a "geometric" proof of Hilbert's 90 in this particular case. Note that the integers $X=a^2 - b^2, Y=2ab, Z=a^2 + b^2 $ form a Pythagorean triple because $u^2 + v^2=1$, and all such triples can be obtained in this way.

Answer (score -4):

You could try proving by contradiction by assuming that $x^2+1$ is a perfect square for some $x∈\mathbb{Z}$ then show how this cannot be possible

Comment: That's what I did (or am trying to do).

Comment: Um, that was the *first* sentence of the OP.